# Powershell : How do I output a filename in an excel column with a specific pattern without renaming original file

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm pretty new to Powershell and I'm trying to parse information from multiple text files into an Excel spreadsheet.

The parsing part is working well but I'm having issues on the filename part.
My files are named like this :

AB0000.123

AB0123.234

AB4567.752

I would like to have the filename in the first column in an Excel spreadsheet to look like this:

123-0000

234-0123

752-4567

The extension first then the 4 digits separated by a "-"
But I don't want the original files to be renamed only the names in the column.

For the moment I've come up with this :

```
ForEach ($file in $files){
   
$location = $root+"\"+$file

#Filename in first column 
$file_name = $file.Basename
$row = $i
$Column = 1
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "$file_name"
```

Which return the filename with the extension, but I don't know how to rearrange the characters.

Comment: grab the `.BaseName` and `.Extension` properties, remove the non-digits from the base name,  then put the remainder into your new string.

Comment: Thanks that worked, had some trouble including leading zeros but I managed to find a fix .

Comment: kool! glad to help ... and that you got things working as you want them ... [*grin*]